# How to put * and whitespace in a Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to build an ASCII array, for a brute-force script, and i need to put * and a whitespace in the array, but nothing seems to works.

I've tried this:

```
array[5]=*
array[5]="*"
array[5]='*'
array[5]=\*
array[5]="\*"
array[5]='\*'
```

but all of this commands expands * to all files in current working directory, or at least put a "*" in the array.

Same story for whitespace. How can I solve this?

Comment: The assignment `array[5]=*` is fine; it's how you *use* `array[5]` later that is causing your problem.

Comment: When you use the variable, you must quote it: `echo "${array[5]}"`

Comment: You can examine the contents of the array: `array[5]="*"; declare -p array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assignments behave identically:

```
array[5]=*
array[5]="*"
array[5]='*'
```

because pathname expansion is not performed on the RHS of an assignment. However, pathname expansion *is* performed on the *unquoted expansion* of a parameter:

```
$ echo "${array[5]}"
*
$ echo ${array[5]}
[every file in the current directory]
```

The RHS of an assignment also does not undergo word-splitting, but you still need to quote *literal* whitespace.

```
$ foo="a b"
$ bar=$foo
$ printf '%s\n' "$bar"
a b
$ printf '%s\n' $bar
a
b
```